# Poisson Distribution Word Problem

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

[image]

The image you are looking is a solution to a problem that has been cropped out. I'm certain the solution is incorrect  since it does not include P(X=2). Just to be on the overly safe side, I decided to verify this on stack exchange. I got an answer of roughly 0.55.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is correct. It does not include $P(X = 2)$ because the question asks what the probability that there are ***at least*** two flaws in a tape is. This is equivalent to $P(X \geq 2)$, as denoted in the solution. You do not include two because, as the solution shows, 
$$P(X\geq 2) = 1- [(P(X=0) + P(X=1)]
$$
 the two other cases in the Poisson process. You would include $P(X=2)$ in the terms subtracted were the question asking what the probability was that there were ***more than*** two flaws in a tape.

Comment: Ahhhhhh thanks. My train of thought was $P(X\geq 2)$ reads the probability that X is greater than or equal to 2

Comment: @KapookyHandy Glad I could help. Remember to surround your MathJax with "\$"!

Comment: @KapookyHandy Nearly! ___Surround___ your math with "\$", don't just place one in front.

Comment: @Kapooky Handy, that is what it reads. You could work it out for x=2, x=3, x=4, and so on and add then up. It's hard, because there's an infinite number to add up, but it converges quite quickly. However, we know that the sum of all of the probabilities (x=0,1,2,3,4,...) is 1 (because something has to happen), so it's easier to start with that and subtract the probabilities for x=0 and x=1.

Comment: Just for practice, $P(X\ > 2) = 1- [(P(X=0) + P(X=1)+ (P(X=2)]$ ? EDIT: Where can I find the guidelines on learning this type of coding notation.

Comment: @KapookyHandy There you go, nearly. There is a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that you might want to take a look at, and you can either download MathJax, or view the preview for your questions below your question (the math typesetting will appear) to get the hang of it. I appreciate you wanting to learn to typeset your questions properly!

Answer (score 2):

"At least two" means the same as "neither zero nor one". That means the easiest way to calculate the probability is to calculate the probability of "either zero or one" and reverse it. There is no need to include the calculation of $P(X=2)$.